# how do i get the sum of the 4th column

Tags: sql

this statement will generate a 4 column table:

```
SELECT shipped.badguy AS badguy, shipped.sdate AS LineDate,
        'Delivery' AS Legend, -price*quantity AS amount
    FROM product JOIN shipped ON (product.id = shipped.product)
UNION
  SELECT receipt.badguy, receipt.rdate,notes, amount
  FROM receipt
```

how do i get the total sum of the 4th of column of what the above generates?

Comment: Your query appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use subqueries for everything.

```
SELECT SUM(results.amount)
FROM
(
SELECT -price*quantity AS amount 
    FROM product JOIN shipped ON (product.id = shipped.product) 
UNION 
  SELECT amount 
  FROM  
...
) results
```

Comment: sql: errorEvery derived table must have its own alias
number: 1248

Comment: Oh, yeah, you'll need an alias for the subquery. I'll add it.

Comment: In Oracle, subquery expressions do not require aliases.  `select count(dummy) from (select * from dual);` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM(-price*quantity)
```

huh?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sum(price*quantity)
```

or combine both query as

```
SELECT badguy,rdate,notes,SUM(AMOUNT) FROM(
        SELECT shipped.badguy AS badguy, shipped.sdate AS LineDate, 
        'Delivery' AS Legend, -price*quantity AS amount 
    FROM product JOIN shipped ON (product.id = shipped.product) 
UNION 
  SELECT receipt.badguy, receipt.rdate,notes, amount 
  FROM) A
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query in another query, where the outer query just gets the sum you want. This makes your query a *subquery*.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (
   SELECT shipped.badguy AS badguy, shipped.sdate AS LineDate,
           'Delivery' AS Legend, -price*quantity AS amount
       FROM product JOIN shipped ON (product.id = shipped.product)
   UNION
     SELECT receipt.badguy, receipt.rdate,notes, amount
     FROM <...>
)
```